# Hosting a asp.net web api on linux with nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, asp.net-web-api, mono, fastcgi

I am trying to host an asp.net web api on linux with mono and nginx. Any mvc web application (*.aspx) will host perfectly, but if I try to host a web api (*.asax) I'll get an error (403).

I've installed mono and nginx correctly. My virtual host configuration are working for mvc web application, but not for an asp.net web api.

My virtual host configuration looks like this (I've added Global.asax as a possible index file and replaced index.aspx with Global.asax in the location "/"):

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/webapp/;
    index index.html index.htm index.aspx Global.asax default.aspx;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /Global.asax;
    }

    location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm also using fastcgi. This is a simple startup script for fastcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
[cutting out....]

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/mono
NAME=monoserver
DESC=monoserver

MONOSERVER=$(which fastcgi-mono-server4)
MONOSERVER_PID=$(ps auxf | grep fastcgi-mono-server4.exe | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

WEBAPPS="mydomain.com:/:/var/www/webapp"

case "$1" in
        start)
                if [ -z "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
                        echo "starting mono server"
                        ${MONOSERVER} /applications=${WEBAPPS} /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 &
                        echo "mono server started"
[cutting out....]
```

All these settings are working fine with a normal aspx web page, but if I try to host a web api, I'll get an error like this: `Error 403 Server Error in '/' Application This type of page is not served.`
If I try to host this web api on windows with iis, everything works finde, so I think the configuration should be okay.
Has anyone an idea, what my problem exactly is?

Comment: Has someone an idea?

Comment: Whats exactly in the logfiles, and when you use curl -i what do the headers say and who is returning the error (nginx or a backend)? you might want to enable debug with the error.log file to see more details.